# vba throws "Run-time error '1004' Method 'Caption' of object 'button' failed", but only on mac

Tags: vba, macos, excel

So i automated some parts of an excel workbook. In the code I add some buttons to certain worksheets. Everything seemed to work just fine until a colleague, working on a mac, got the following error: **Run-time error '1004': Method 'Caption' of object 'Button' failed**.

I checked it out and apparently the error only occurs on 1 specific worksheet. I tried deleting that specific workbook and creating a new one, but the error still occurs on that specific worksheet.

This is my code:

```
Dim btn As Button
Set btn = Sheet2.Buttons.Add(400, 5, 100, 50)
With btn
    .OnAction = "add_feature_click"
    .Caption = "ADD FEATURE"
    .name = "add_feature"
End With
Set btn = Sheet2.Buttons.Add(510, 5, 100, 50)
With btn
    .OnAction = "add_phase_click"
    .Caption = "ADD PHASE"
    .name = "add_phase"
End With
Set btn = Sheet3.Buttons.Add(400, 5, 100, 50)
With btn
    .OnAction = "Add_Feature_click"
    .Caption = "ADD FEATURE" '<--
    .name = "add_feature"
End With
Set btn = Sheet3.Buttons.Add(510, 5, 100, 50)
With btn
    .OnAction = "add_phase_click"
    .Caption = "ADD PHASE"
    .name = "add_phase"
End With
```

So creating the buttons in "Sheet2" works fine, but throws an error on "Sheet3" when executed on mac. (The same code is used to add buttons to 6 different worksheets and works fine in all the others)

Edit: the error occurs on the line with the commented arrow

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Sheet 3 is the only part that has a different .OnAction then the other sheets. I suggest bringing it in line with the rest of your statements.

Comment: That was a copy issue, i shortened the names for privacy reasons, i'll edit that

Comment: Well for some reason your caption is invalid. So it probably is related to the text you are trying to allocate to it. Perhaps you are making use of any special characters?

Comment: The caption i use is the same as in the code here, if i comment that line the same error occurs on the .name . If i comment the whole button, the same 2 errors occur with the next button. If i comment both buttons the code executes just fine. I think the issue is in the worksheet, but i have no idea what the problem might be

Comment: Is there anything that is different in worksheet 3 compared to other worksheets, maybe its name?

Comment: Just guessing - what if you change the captions so there are no duplicate captions?  E.g., `ADD` (one space) `FEATURE` on `Sheet2` and `ADD` (two spaces) `FEATURE` on `Sheet3`?

Comment: A [related forum post](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/729204-help-needed-runtime-error-1004-select-method-button-class-failed.html)

Comment: Worksheet3 is called "backlog", and worksheet2 is called "backlog empty". they are an exact copy, except that "backlog empty" (as the name suggests) is empty. It only has the standard formulas and layout that is needed. I don't think there are any other differences between the 2 worksheets.

Comment: @cxw I tried what u suggested, but didn't work. (i Added a 1 behind the captions of the second worksheet)

Comment: Do you mean the "Add feature" and "Add phase" functions? basically they will insert a line on the right spot so the formulas keep working. We've had trouble with people adding a line manually in the wrong place and therefor breaking the whole file. The same function is used by other buttons as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, I assumed you used "Dim as button", and I ran it on a clean workbook in both 2011 and 2016 Excel for Mac and it works fine to add the buttons.

Comment: oh, misunderstood your question then. But yes on top of the function i declare 'btn' with 'Dim btn As Button'. I'll add that to the code in the question for clarification. I also want tot state that the error only occurs on a mac.

Comment: OK - two thoughts: **1** assign `.Name` before assigning any other properties, and make sure the `.Name` values are unique (e.g., `add_feature`, `add_feature1`.  **2** Are the `add_feature_click` and `add_phase_click` `Sub`s accessible from `Sheet3`?  If they are on `Sheet2`, set `OnAction="Sheet2.add_feature_click"` &c.  (From [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/error-cannot-run-the-macro-macroname-the-macro-may/5c817864-9405-40fc-bc94-dfe771829c23))

Comment: (for `OnAction`, `Sheet2` is the VBA name of the sheet, not the name visible in the main Excel window, e.g., `backlog empty`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the code at the error, then go to the created button, right click and Properties, what happens when you attempt to manually set the Caption?

Comment: I'm not able to set it manually. When i click "Edit text" nothing happens

Comment: If you get the Edit Text option when you right click it, I think you are creating a Forms button rather than an ActiveX button, and I don't think form buttons have properties in the same way such as Caption.  Not sure why this is only an issue in the second button though.

Comment: Something like the below should generate an ActiveX button that you should be able to assign properties to:

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=123.75, Top:=313.5, Width:=72, Height:= _
        24)